# nginx - differentiating between localhost and server IP

Tags: nginx, node.js

I've migrated from LAMP stack to nodejs + nginx in front , and amazed by running different applications on different ports. currently my nginx contains:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /srv/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://nulll.me/$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        root /srv/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /home/---------------.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/--------------.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /app1 {
            proxy_pass http://SERVER_IP_ADDR:8888;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

        location /app2 {
            proxy_pass http://SERVER_IP_ADDR:5555;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Now from this conf what I wanted was to introduce different apps that are already running no different ports eg. 8888 , 5555 etc which I'm accomplishing by `proxy_pass http://SERVER_IP_ADDR:8888;`. And I have some applications that I need to communicate internally by binding them to localhost ports `eg. 127.0.0.1:6666` and I don't want them to be available outside my machine.

So my question is , does Nginx gets request on port 80 / or ssl port and routes that request to /app1 or /app2 that I've proxy-passed and returns the response while protecting those ports ? Or can anyone access those ports that I've bind to localhost:someport ? Or if they're visible , how do I make them protected so that even on accessing those ports (http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:8070) nginx or something blocks them and can only be accessed by nginx when routing request.

I'm confused because I've to specify : `proxy_pass http://SERVER_IP_ADDR:8888;` my machine's IP ADDRESS. Can't I do this as `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;` , because nginx can listen to those applications right away on localhost , being on same machine?

***TLDR;*** What I want is to block direct access of different ports on my machine by other peeps and only in machine processes should be able to communicate with those ports. So nginx should get a request on normal http/s port and forward it to some other node application running on lets say 8888 port and return request. But people shouldn't be able to access like this : http://My_SERVER_IP:8080/. Thanks

**Edit**: *If there is any way I could configure Nginx to listen to all ports except 80/443 and listen to 80/443 separately , so that all other ports are invisible to outside but can be communicated and connected by in processes , that would do too.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. bind your services to loopback addresses. That way, noone will be able to access them from outside the computer..
2. use firewall to block all incoming connections to ports that are not supposed to be visible from outside
3. do not try to make nginx listen on all ports. You will get into more trouble than it's worth.

You'll get best results sticking to all three points.

Comment: 1. Does that mean binding them to 127.0.0.1:some-port? And then making nginx listen them as `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:some-port;`. And what would be a good firewall , I considered Iptables , but people often say they locked themselves out of their servers.

Comment: Exactly. But nginx will not be listening for them, but connecting to those services. iptables is the default choice on linux. Possibly with some script bundle that makes it easier to setup, like ufw, or shorewall. People locked out of their own servers is not iptables fault. It is the administrators fault. And as SF is site about professional use of information technology, I expect your site is not a for-fun experiment. Then please, leave this to a professional. Or start studying. A lot!

Comment: Thankyou :) and I meant to say I won't be able to setup a good Iptable rules by stating that line , and thanks to you for recommending ufw. That would be choice to do this. :)